# How to import and export excel in angular and asp.net core project

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

Can anyone help me, How to import and export the excel file in angular and asp.net core project with using Entity Core Framework?

**I have an Excel file it contains 10 sheets, When I import excel sheet into SQL server it will create 10 tables related to sheet name. IN ASP.NET CORE AND ANGULAR PROJECT**

Comment: Please provide more info. What do you want to achieve? What do you mean by importing an Excel file? Upload / download files to store them on the server (not excel specific though) or import _data_ from an Excel file into a database via EF? Or s.g. else? BTW, I just see that it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041960/export-and-download-excel-at-asp-net-core-and-angular-project

Answer (score -1):

**I Got it guy's**

**This is Import the excel into SQL server in ASP.NET Core and Angular Project**

> already we have (test.xlsx)excel file in WWWROOT folder in the project and then do below code

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using OfficeOpenXml;

using System;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

using System.IO;

namespace ArchDVS.Controllers

{

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]

[ApiController]

public class ExcelController : ControllerBase

{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;


    public ExcelController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)

    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }
    [HttpGet, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    [Route("Import")]
    public string Import()
    {
        string sWebRootFolder = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        //var excelFile = new FileInfo(@"TestFile.xlsx");
        string sFileName = @"test.xlsx";
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(sWebRootFolder, sFileName));

        using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=sivan.nsp\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DVS;Integrated Security=True;"))
        {
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                using (ExcelPackage epPackage = new ExcelPackage(file))
                {
                    var worksheet = epPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                    for (var row = 1; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
                    {
                        var rowValues = worksheet.Cells[row, 1, row, worksheet.Dimension.End.Column];
                        var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO test(ID, Name, Gender, Salary) VALUES (@contactid, @firstname, @secondname, @age)", con);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactid", rowValues["A1"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", rowValues["B1"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secondname", rowValues["C1"].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", rowValues["D1"].Value);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                }
                return "sucessfully uploded";
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                return "Some error occured while importing." + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}